# Is there any way to enable IPv6 forwarding without enabling other assumptions, particularly IsRouter on ND packets?

Tags: routing, ipv6

I notice in the documentation that enabling IPv6 forwarding sets an "IsRouter" flag on the Neighbour Discovery packets sent by the host.  In fact it's stated that when enabling forwarding "Router behaviour is assumed".

This might have seemed good logic, but it does exclude the edge case of IPv6 NATs *(yes they are rare)*.  For example a container host (Docker) running a NAT'd virtual network on a ULA subnet `fc00::/64`.  The internal networking is all configured by the container software (Docker) and doesn't use ND.  But to the external LAN the host is just one Host and not a router to anywhere else.

It makes little / no sense for the host to advertise itself as router.

I'm unclear on whether or not the host is advertising to the LAN that it has a route to `fc00::/64`.  This could be bad because there may be many hosts on the same LAN all advertising access to the same subnet.

Is there any way to enable IPv6 `forwarding` without enabling other assumptions, particularly `IsRouter` on ND packets?

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt

```
forwarding - INTEGER
    Configure interface-specific Host/Router behaviour.

    Note: It is recommended to have the same setting on all
    interfaces; mixed router/host scenarios are rather uncommon.

    Possible values are:
        0 Forwarding disabled
        1 Forwarding enabled

    FALSE (0):

    By default, Host behaviour is assumed.  This means:

    1. IsRouter flag is not set in Neighbour Advertisements.
    2. If accept_ra is TRUE (default), transmit Router
       Solicitations.
    3. If accept_ra is TRUE (default), accept Router
       Advertisements (and do autoconfiguration).
    4. If accept_redirects is TRUE (default), accept Redirects.

    TRUE (1):

    If local forwarding is enabled, Router behaviour is assumed.
    This means exactly the reverse from the above:

    1. IsRouter flag is set in Neighbour Advertisements.
    2. Router Solicitations are not sent unless accept_ra is 2.
    3. Router Advertisements are ignored unless accept_ra is 2.
    4. Redirects are ignored.

    Default: 0 (disabled) if global forwarding is disabled (default),
         otherwise 1 (enabled).
```

Comment: And it appears that mangling ICMPv6 with nftables to remove the offending bit as a workaround doesn't recompute the checksum leading to a dropped packet. Anyway to advertise its route it should be running [radvd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radvd) so I don't think that's so important.